# Trying to give a class a tuple for two arguments

Tags: python

So I wanted certain coordinates in my code to have a range so heres a snipet of my code

```
enemy_spawns = [
    (48, random.randint(470, 535)), (random.randint(920, 980), 26),
    (1842, random.randint(470, 535)), (random.randint(920, 980), 1034)
```

and then I wanted to put them in a class as seperate x and y

```
class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, x, y, speed):
```

but when I assign it to the class it acts as one argument.

I tried doing this

```
    enemy_coords = []
    coords = random.choice(enemy_spawns)
    enemy_coords.append(coords.split(','))
    print(enemy_coords)
```

but I can't split tuples

Comment: you can access the two elements inside the tuple with their indexes like coords[0], coords[1]

Comment: `enemy_coords.append(coords)`?? It's unclear what you are trying to do - no part of your code in the last block has anything to do with your class. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello and good day to you,
tuple objects don't have the function split if you want to extract a member of them you can use `coords[0]`.
split is for string class if you want to use split you can do this:

```
enemy_spawns = ["48 , " + str(randint(470, 535)), str(randint(980, 920)) + ", 26"]
enemy_spawns[0].split(",")
```

now split() will work

Answer (score 1):

Why not just do:

```
enemy_coords = random.choice(enemy_spawns)
```

And take a tuple as an argument in your init, and then go on from there?

Comment: Cause I wanted seperate x and y otherwise I would've had to change a lot of stuff. It's fine though i just set the x to enemy_coords[0] and enemy_coords[1]. Thanks anyways.